# Laravel Nova - Model static::saved event will not load relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-nova

I'm using Laravel Nova on my main application and I'm having an issue with model events from certain contexts.

When a new `Post` model is created, I store the '*Latest Post Date*' against the `User`. I do this by using model events:

```php
static::saved(function (Post $post) {
    $post->author->latest_post_date = data_get($post->author->latestPost(), 'latest_post_date');
    $post->author->save();
});
```

When a post is saved, it grabs the latest `Post` by that author, and stores the field in `latest_post_date`. This supports editing an existing `Post` to adjust the post's date and creating. It always selects the correct latest post date.

I've tests supporting this, and it's working as expected throughout my application and in production.

The issue I have is in Laravel Nova: when a new `Post` is created in Nova, the `Post` passed to the model event is fully devoid of all relations - which means I get `null` upon requesting `$post->author`.

Within the model event, I've tried the following:

1. `$post->refresh();`
2. `$post->load('author');`
3. `$post->author()->first();`

All of the above returns `null` on those relationships within the model event, only when triggered through Laravel Nova.

The `$post->author_id` field is correctly stored with the correct `author_id` value, however, even the following returns `null` within the model event:

```php
Author::find($post->author_id)
```

The `Author` definitely exists and is **not** created as part of this process.

I've dug through the Laravel Nova `Resource` class and all relevant traits to see if I can identify the point in which the model's relations are stripped out, or perhaps a property that explicitly disables them but to no avail (though I may have missed it, some of that code is dense).

I've also tried replicating this logic by overloading the `Resource` `afterCreate` method, but this has the same behavior.

The issue *only* exists when the `Post` is created directly via Laravel Nova; when creating the `Post` within the context of my application, it works as expected.

Has anyone experienced something similar? Or are you able to replicate perhaps to help me track down what's going on here?

Comment: if `Author::find($post->author_id)` does not work, I don't think your problem is with nova

Comment: @krisgjika when this same model event fires via my main application, `Author::find($post->author_id)` returns correctly. The *only* time it doesn't, is when the model event is triggered from a Nova action

Comment: I am very confused because you are not sharing enough code, so your issue is that, when you create a new `Post` using the Nova UI, your `Post` model (when `boot` -> `static::saved` is triggered), the `$post->author` inside the event method is `null`? And, even running `$post->load('author')` does not "reload" the relationship? Something seems off, not related to Nova, I did use Nova (even v4) and did not had this issue at all, used plenty of events like you are and works perfectly fine. What Nova version are you using? And do you have any attributes or traits on the model?

Comment: Could you try to reproduce this with a new normal model? Create a model called `Work`, for example, with just a single editable field and relate it to your `Author` model with `author_id` on it (`BelongsTo`). Then, on Nova, create a `Work` entry and try accessing the author and see what happens (of course you need to have an author already assigned to it, else it will always be `null`). Check if your `author_id` is filled (at least), so we can discard that, magically, the field is being nullified

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else encounters the same, I'll update with what was actually happening in the background.

I had a global scope on my Author model that depended on some authentication data.

This meant that when I was using the site from either my tests (which use `$this->actingAs(...)`), or my main application which is 'logged-in only', the authentication data was present, and all relevant models were related to that authentication data.

However, as I'm logged in as an 'admin' user within Nova, it meant the authentication data wasn't present, or didn't relate to the record I was updating.

A quirk of the way Nova works means it didn't throw an exception, but rather just failed quietly and refused to load the relation. So from Nova, the relation was null (even if I tried to load it directly) without any error, but from the main site the relation was filled correctly.

An exception instead of a quiet fail would have saved some serious time, but that's not the crux of this issue.

In order to circumvent this, within my global scope's `apply` method, I did the following:

```
Nova::whenServing(
    function () {}, // What to apply when Nova is serving
    function () use (&$builder) { // The default behaviour
        $builder->where(...); // Apply the scope
    });
```

By default the scope is applied, but when Nova is serving, it does not. This meant I was able to administer the site correctly via Nova *and* users were able to administer their own data freely via the main site.